# How to terminate an async function in discord.py from another command

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py, terminate

I'm using `discord.ext.commands` to make a discord bot. I made a command that constantly keeps unbanning people even if someone is banned. This is the code:

```py
@client.command(name="unban")
async def unban(ctx):
  while True:
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()
    if(len(bans)>0):
      for ban in bans:
        ctx.guild.unban(ban)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

But this is a while loop so I want to terminate this function through another command (say, stop_unban). So I want to know how to terminate the `unban` function through another function (associated with the stop_unban command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would be to use a global bool variable that both functions can access to control the banning state.
For example:

```
ban_state = False
@client.command(name="unban")
async def unban(ctx):
  global ban_state
  ban_state = True
  while ban_state:
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()
    if(len(bans)>0):
      for ban in bans:
        await ctx.guild.unban(ban.user)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
@client.command(name="stop_unban")
async def stop_unban(ctx):
  global ban_state
  ban_state = False
  await ctx.send('Unban Mode stopped')
```

However, another potentially nicer solution if you want the unban mode to last for long periods as well as not using global variables could be to use a `background task` instead of the `while True`.
For example:

```
from discord.ext import tasks
@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def unbanning(ctx):
    bans = await ctx.guild.bans()
    if(len(bans)>0):
      for ban in bans:
        await ctx.guild.unban(ban.user) #btw you need to await this and you have provide the user attribute of the ban not just the ban itself
    
@client.command(name="unban")
async def unban(ctx):
  unbanning.start(ctx)
@client.command(name="stop_unban")
async def stop_unban(ctx):
  unbanning.cancel()
```

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) is more info on background tasks :)

Comment: Good answer @x-1-x, though one tiny nit is I'd suggest you could remove the `asyncio.sleep(5)` from the background task version -- background tasks implicitly sleep already -- and just make it loop every 5 seconds instead.  That way it's functionally about the same as the while loop version

Comment: @lemonhead nice spot! Didn't see that line :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually tried the global variable method. But my program was making a new local variable with the same name. I didn't know about the global keyword.